# parsing an html page and sending the parsed data to a another page

Tags: javascript

I'm required to pass an entire content of an html, in a manner that the blank html page (the destination) will be the exact duplicate of the source page.

My idea was to some how send the HTMLHeadElement and the HTMLBodyElement innerHtml's 
and some how  parse them on the other side.

```
        var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var head_source = headElement.innerHTML;

        var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var body_source = bodyElement.innerHTML;
```

My dilemmas are plentiful and I hope some one would address the general problem 
and how to approach this assignment. I just need a push in the right direction.

So on the receiving side I'll find some way to parse the expression being sent, and build my document using the DOM approach.

My problems are:

(1) my source document (source.htm) as a form with a submit control,
 how could I overload the submit function in order to send the
 strings body_source and head_source along side the forms values?
 (the forms action="destPage.html" method="get").

(2) is the method "get" even an option in the manner in which I'm attempting to pass this info through ?

(3) I'm pretty much open to any suggestions on how to duplicate sourcePage.htm on to destPage.htm. , maybe my approach is flawed.

Comment: i'd also be most appreciative if someone could edit the title of the question to something more searchable for other users 
i couldn't think of any thing shorter and more to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a recursion problem with what you are trying to do. Whatever language you are using to read your POSTed variables should have no problem just pulling the the submitting page's html via an include or a filesystem call.

Maybe I'm missing the point.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an approach where you populate a hidden form field with the value of the current document like so:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="page2.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="content">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form[name="myForm"]').submit(function(){
        $(this).children('input[name="content"]').val($('html').html());
    });
});
```

You would then need to retrieve that data from the post headers sent to the server using PHP or some other sort of server side script. In PHP this would be very easy:

```
echo $_POST['content'];
```

and voila, your page is identical. Of course, I too may be missing the point.

Comment: what your suggesting involve JQuery right ?
' and on the destination i'm not suppose to know how many controls i got .
what i was hoping to do is loop is write the string containing the 
the inneHtml on the other side and then appending it as the documents child. 

ill cross that bridge when i get to it ...
what i want to know is how to pass thous values to the other side.
when i press on submit in my form .

Comment: i'm required to do this using java-script but thanks for the suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

How about sending URL of source.htm and then using that URL to load contents of source.htm into destPage.htm with AJAX? You can use jQuery `.load` for copying contents from one page to another (as long as rules of same origin policy are not violated). Not sure if I got your question right...

Comment: i don't think any one got my question right :(

lets say you had to dynamically build a page head and body .
with the same style and attributes , and the same body which includes a form that incorporated a table and what not...
how would you parse this information and send it to your destination?